# Storyboard ipad in landscape orientation only

Tags: ipad, storyboard, landscape

I'm creating an iPad application that supports ONLY LANDSDCAPE mode. I'm using storyboards.

Even after doing the below, while the simulator starts up in the landscape mode, the application starts up in the portrait mode only. Pls help in how can I make the application start up in landscape mode and retain that mode throughout.

1. shouldautorotate is set YES for landscape
2. initial interface orientation in info.plist is set to landscape
3. supported interface orientation in info.plist is set to landscape
4. simulated metrics for viewcontrollers are set to inferred.

thanks in advance for the help. I've searched on the web but the answer to this is not available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under simulated metric choose "Landscape".

Also make sure you have this method in your view controller implementations:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

Comment: @user, Did you add the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method to all your view controller implementations? See above for code.

Comment: Yes thank you!!! :-) I solved the problem by making the storyboard class point to a subclass of the UIviewController class where the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is also coded. This has to be done for each implemented ViewController. This was my mistake (oops!) ;-(.

I thought storyboard would take care of the landscape implementation all by itself, but I guess it does not till we associate a UIViewController subclass with it.

Is there anyway I can do it directly in storyboard without coding the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation???

Thanks for your answers

Comment: I must stay the same issue got me and my solution was as above. Aren't storyboards supposed to reduce code? However we are required to sub-class a controller JUST to set the auto rotate setting?? The orientation under "simulated Metrics" has no effect when applied to a view within a storyboard. This must surely be a bug.

Comment: No, "Simulated Metrics" are just simulations of certain situations that may or may not occur. IE, you can have it simulate the bar being extended as if the device is currently recording audio, so you know how your layout looks under that scenario. It is not a bug that Simulated Metrics don't change how your app actually behaves.